# Inject JS into a live site from localhost

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, browser-sync

I'm working with Monetate, a testing tool which injects JS into our clients sites once the targeted page has loaded. Although Monetate is great for tests it is not good for developing and there is no community for it. I'm looking for a way to have a dev setup (express server, gulp task runner, sass etc) and to dynamically inject the JS and CSS files into our clients sites, simulating Monetate. I've been trying browser-sync but I can't seem to inject files from my local server into a live site. Any ideas would be most welcome!

Comment: Only with cooperation from either the site or the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. I've been using the extension 'Custom JavaScript for Websites' for Chrome. Which works well but would like to make the process more automated.